# Клиент-Сервер на Java

Tags: java, сеть, клиент-сервер, ip

Написал на Java простенький клиент и сервер на сокетах для чатика. На localhost все работает просто замечательно. Но как сделать так чтобы была возможность подключиться к моему серверу с клиента, который может находится где угодно, а не только в моей сети. Пробовал подключаться серверу с другом через Hamachi, все прекрасно работает. Знаю что есть внешний/локальный IP. Если я подключу свою машину напрямую к интернету(а не через роутер) выйдет ли что-то из этого? Разворачивать приложение на каком нибудь Tomcat и заливать на хостинг не очень хочется. Может есть какой то другой способо?

Comment: другого способа с динамическим IP - нет. Для этого есть DNS или хостинги.

Comment: А какое отношение имеет вопрос к java? Ведь в приложении всё работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, вы можете запустить сервер вашего чата из дома у себя на компьютере, и кто угодно сможет подключиться, но для этого у вас должен быть **белый статический IP**. Если в двух словах, то белые статические IP адреса, это публичные адреса, которые видны всему интернету. Они закрепляются за конкретными устройствами на долгое время. Для того, чтобы получить такой IP, обратитесь к вашему интернет-провайдеру. Большинство из них предоставляют такие возможности, но как правило берут за это ежемесячную плату.
Если за вами не закреплен белый статический IP адрес, то толку никакого не будет, хоть через роутер, хоть напрямую через интернет-кабель.
Про белые и серые адреса можно почитать [здесь](https://help.keenetic.net/hc/ru/articles/213965789-%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-)